# linq query group by fail to group all rows with similar keys

Tags: c#, linq

this is my query:

```
rows.GroupBy(row => new TaxGroupObject
            {
                EnvelopeID = row.Field<int>("EnvelopeID"),
                PolicyNumber = row.Field<string>("PolicyNumber"),
                TZ = row.Field<string>("TZ")
            })
            .Select(row =>

                        {
                            int i;
                            if (row.Key.EnvelopeID == 5713 && row.Key.PolicyNumber == "50002617" && row.Key.TZ == "50002617") 
                                i=1+1;
                            var newRow = structure.NewRow();
                            newRow["PolicyNumber"]=row.Key.PolicyNumber;
                            newRow["TZ"]=row.Key.TZ;
                            newRow["CreditPremiaTaxParagraph45"] = row.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x["CreditPremiaTaxParagraph45"].ToString()));
                            newRow["WorklossTax"] = row.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x["WorklossTax"].ToString()));
                            newRow["MiscTax"] = row.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x["MiscTax"].ToString()));
                            newRow["EnvelopeID"] = row.Key.EnvelopeID;
                            return newRow;
                        }
            );
    internal class TaxGroupObject
{
    public long? EnvelopeID{ get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public string TZ { get; set; }

}
```

i put a breakpoint on the line with "i=1+1", after an if condition comparing all the keys i've used for the group by with some hard coded values. that break point is being hit twice, although the group by suppose to group all rows with same keys together. the thing is that for most of the values in the table the grouping works just fine and i cant understand how its possible. if you can help in any way it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implemented on `TaxGroupObject`? (hint: not how they should be)

Comment: they arent.i added it to the code. TaxGroupObjec is a simple object with properties and no methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `TaxGroupObject` does not implement [`GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx). These methods are used by `GroupBy` to determine what makes one `TaxGroupObject` object equal to another. By default, it's by reference equality, not property equality.

This should work, using the `GetHashCode` algorithm from [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode):

```
internal class TaxGroupObject
{
    public long? EnvelopeID { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public string TZ { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + EnvelopeID.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (PolicyNumber != null ? PolicyNumber.GetHashCode() : -2);
            hash = hash * 23 + (TZ != null ? TZ.GetHashCode() : -1);
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(TaxGroupObject))
            return false;
        var other = (TaxGroupObject)obj;
        return this.EnvelopeID == other.EnvelopeID &&
                this.PolicyNumber == other.PolicyNumber &&
                this.TZ == other.TZ;
    }
}
```

Also, you should only use immutable objects in something like a grouping or dictionary. At a minimum, you must be sure that the objects here do not change during your grouping.

Comment: It is extremely important that the three properties that the hash code is computed on do not change. They must be changed to getter only properties.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree that they must be immutable for the life of the grouping, and might be best as getter-only depending on how this class is used elsewhere, but to say they *must* be getter-only is a little extreme, IMO.

Comment: @TimS. - Perhaps, but it is worth making the point because some people wouldn't understand the implication. It's also one of those things that we should get into a habit of doing right.

Answer (score 0):

eventually i found it simpler to give up inheritance and use a struct instead of class, it also works since struct is a value type therefore doesn't need equals method override. I am intrested in which of these approaches bring better performance, if anybody knows. Intuitively it seems like structs are more efficient, but I am not sure, and I currently don't have the time to emulate the two options or make the proper re(google)search. 
Thanks